# Installing multiple versions of R in the same Anaconda environment

Tags: anaconda

I have deployed Anaconda to a number R users to enable them to manage their R environment as their local admin rights have been removed.

This is Anaconda 5.1.0 x64 on Windows.

The Anaconda software being used is R and Rstudio.

I have been asked how to install multiple versions of R in the same environment (e.g. the root environment) so the required version can be selected from Rstudio installed in the same environment.

Before the local admin rights were removed they use to installed “native” R and Rstudio i.e. they did not use Anaconda and this is how they worked – one install of Rstudio with multiple versions of R installed, select which one was wanted.

Is it possible to do this within Anaconda?

So far, I can only seem to have one version of R in an environment, installing another overwrites the existing one.

I’ve also tried installing a different version of R in it’s own new environment and then trying to select it from Rstudio installed in the root environment but it either:

Tells me This directory does not appear to contain a valid R                    installation.

Lets me select it but on restarting Rstudio fails with various missing library errors.

Am I correct in assuming that to use multiple versions of R in Anaconda you would need to create an environment for each version and also install Rstudio in each environment as well to be able to select it?

If this is the case would it mean that they would also need to install all their additional R packages in each environment as well?

Apologies if this has already been answered else ware but I have not been able to find an answer.

Comment: have to managed to find a solution?

Comment: No I haven't as yet and to be honest haven't looked in to it any futher due to running out of idea.

Comment: I solved it by installing R with conda (which is the default) and also following normal procedure. So now I have 2 versions of R. Not the most intelligent way, but it works. If I launch Rstudio from terminal it is conda version, If I launch from applications then the other version.

Comment: Anyway, this is a good question, hope to find some smart solution soon.